# ColdFusion's XML Support & Word Documents

Tags: xml, coldfusion, ms-word, docx

Using ColdFusion's new XML functions... is it possible to find/replace text in Word documents (docx)? I was trying to wrap my head around accomplising this since a docx document could have a piece of text (a placeholder to search for) spread out on multiple w:r (runs) which could be difficult to search and replace for.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes.

However, the XML schema MS uses is pretty verbose. I understand that is redundant, but the XML is quite complex.

It might be a better idea to use .NET to manipulate the document and make calls from within CF use the .NET integration. I believe there are also Java libraries, but I am unsure of how easy they are to use or how well they work.

Comment: I have not actually used this but it is a Java library that works with Word documents, might be worth investigating.  I have used their one for Excel XLSM files and was not hard to deal with:  http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have the word document with a replacement word, then extract the .docx file using 7zip's CLI, since it's just an archive, replace the word, and rearchive it. This has been proven to be very effective and doesn't mess with the XML at all.

Here's some sample code from an application that replaces the word '%SENTDATE%'. Not all variables are here, but this should be enough to get you started.

```
<cfset EditFile = Output & "word\document.xml" />

<!--- Extract the New Document --->
<cfexecute name="7za.exe" arguments='x -y "#StartingFile#" -o"#Output#"' outputfile="#Dir#log_Extract.txt" />

<!--- Read in the file --->
<cfset WordDoc = FileRead( EditFile ) />

<!--- Replace Values --->
<cfset WordDoc = Replace( WordDoc, "%SENTDATE%", DateFormat( Now(), "MMMM DD, YYYY" ), "ALL" ) />

<!--- Save File --->
<cfset FileWrite( EditFile, WordDoc ) />

<!--- Delete Archive if it exists --->
<cfif FileExists( NewFile )>
    <cfset FileDelete( NewFile ) />
</cfif>

<!--- Repack Archive --->
<cfexecute name="7za.exe" arguments='a "#NewFile#" "#Output#*"' outputfile="#Dir#log_Archive.txt" />

<!--- Rename Archive --->
<cffile action="rename" source="#NewFile#" destination="#ListFirst( NewFile, "." )#.docx" />
```

Comment: So you are extracting the xml and doing a replace on a placeholder within the xml, then repackaging it. The thing is, if you are dealing with a lot of documents and you delete out text to add a placeholder... Word's underlying XML engine loves to toss your text accross multiple xml elements (they call them runs). So your placeholder will not be searchable unless you take that into account.

Comment: We only replace about six different words in the text, mainly to fill in numbers and haven't run into that issue.